# Limit size of each array value in Postgressql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, maxlength

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST(id int, description varchar(100));

    INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 'The quick brown fox'),
                 (1, 'This is a test to check for data'),
                 (1, 'This is just another test checking data'),
                 (2, 'Data set 2'),
                 (2, 'This is a test for data set 2'),
                 (2, 'Quickest fox catches the worms')
```

I have a query where I'm using the array_agg function to put all descriptions on one field.  Due to size limits I'm trying to only bring back the first 3 characters of each description.

```
    select id, array_agg(id||', ') as ids,
    array_agg(description||', ') as description
    from test
    group by id
```

I was trying to use the length function but I don't see how to limit each value in the array.

Comment: `left(description, 3)`?

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I kept trying length over and over.